# Adding helpers with pybars3

Tags: python, handlebars.js, sendgrid

Sendgrid's email templates are rendered using Handlebars.  In Sendgrid's implementation of Handlebars, there is the [#equals helper](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars#equals).  I am using Python's [pybars3](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars#equals).  In the GitHub readme for pybars3, there is an example of how to add helpers.  How can I implement the #equals helper from Sendgrid into my pybars3 code?

I want it to take in the following HTML, and, depending on the `number_of_plans` variable, either output 'Your Plan' or 'Your Plans'.

```
Your {{#equals number_of_plans 1}}Plan{{else}}Plans{{/equals}}
```

I think it should look something like this:

```
# Get a compiler
from pybars import Compiler
compiler = Compiler()

# helper function; this isn't quite right
def _equals(this, options, v1, v2):
  if v1 == v2:
    options['fn']
  else:
    options['inverse']

helpers = {'equals': _equals}

# Compile the template
source = r'Your {{#equals number_of_plans 1}}Plan{{else}}Plans{{/equals}}'
template = compiler.compile(source)

# render the template
output = template({'number_of_plans': 1}, helpers = helpers)
```

However, the output is 'Your Plans,' not 'Your Plan.'  What am I doing wrong?